# Deno: how do I connect to oracle database?

Tags: oracle, deno

For a rest service written in DENO - i.e Nodejs replacement, I need to query oracle database.

How can I do that? Any examples?

Note: I do see postgres libs, but that's not my current need.

Note2: If currently no solution, just make the question more visible so the 'gods' know that there is a popular-demand.

Comment: Sorry no Oracle drivers at this point my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Deno is pretty young, I doubt that we already an Oracle driver implemented in Deno (But I might be wrong). If you want to build a production-ready application I suggest you to stick with Node.js until Deno has all the libraries and driver that you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the third-party libraries available for [Deno here.](https://deno.land/x/)  There is limited database support. Check out this library for [MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL](https://deno.land/x/denodb). Not sure there's any for Oracle.